# How to customize invoice page in Ubercart 3

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

i need to customize the page that user sees at url: user/%user/orders/%uc_order

i tried to use hook_uc_order_pane

```
function mymodule_uc_order_pane() {
  $panes['ship_to_xx'] = array(
  'callback' => 'mymodule_uc_order_pane_ship_to_xx',
  'title' => t('Just a Test'),
  'desc' => t("Description!!"),
  'class' => 'pos-left',
  'weight' => 99,
  'show' => array('view', 'edit', 'invoice', 'customer'),
  );
  return $panes;
}
```

and cleared all cache, but this doesn't work. It doesn't display anything.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I guess you'll find more luck on http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was not wrong.
The correct way to do it is:

```
function mymodule_uc_order_pane() {
    $panes['mm_links'] = array(
    'callback' => 'mymodule_uc_order_pane_links',
    'title' => t('Just a Test'),
    'desc' => t("Description!!"),
    'class' => 'pos-left',
    'weight' => 99,
    'show' => array('customer'),
    );
    return $panes;
}

function mymodule_uc_order_pane_links($op,$order){
    $html='';
    foreach($order->products as $product){
        $node = node_load($product->nid);
        $html.='Date: '.$product->data['attributes']['Tour Date'][0].'<br/>';
        $html.='Parent ID: '.$node->field_tour['und'][0]['nid'].'<br/>';
    }   
    return ($html);
}
```

Comment: Better yet is to use a switch($op) in mymodule_uc_order_pane_links.
In this case possible $op are 'customer' for pane body, 'show_title', true or false to display title and 'view-title' to define title content.
Also would be better to use Drupal's theming functions than to write  raw HTML. i.e: $build = array('#markup' => $html);return $build;